# Python Scraping for String to get an Alarm

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I think I've got to a point where I need help from professionals. I would like to build a scraper for a browser game that gives an alarm to a bot (Telegram or Discord). The connection of the bot is not the problem at first, it is more about getting the right result.

My script runs in a while-loop (it also runs without) and is supposed to look for links in an -tag. These links contain an ID. This is always incremented +1 when a new player signs up to the game and that's exactly what I need.
Since I need to compare the information, I figured I need to save it in a .csv file. And there lies the problem the output looks like this in the .csv:

> index.php?section=impressum

I have two problems:

1. I want to limit the output to the first 5 results in the file
2. Only have in the file if something changes or the corresponding change.

[1. + 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo6rS.jpg)

This ist my code so far:

```
import requests
import time
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def writeCSV(data):
    csv_file = open('ags_scrape.csv', 'w')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow([data])
    csv_file.close()


sleepTimer = 3

# Adresse der Webseite
url = "https://www.ag-spiel.de/"
allAGs = []
firstRun = True

while True:
    response = requests.get(url + "index.php?section=live")

    # BeautifulSoup HTML-Dokument aus dem Quelltext parsen
    html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # url aus dem <a href> parsen
    newDetected = False
    newAGs = []
    possible_links = html.find_all('a')

    for link in possible_links:
        if link.has_attr('href'):
            inhalt = str(link.attrs['href'])

        if "aktie=" in inhalt:
            if firstRun is True:
                allAGs.append(inhalt)
            else:
                if str(inhalt) not in allAGs:
                    newDetected = True
                    print("ATTENTION!!! New AG! Url is: " + inhalt)
                    allAGs.append(inhalt)
                    # in Datei schreiben
                    writeCSV(inhalt)

        else:
            # print ("Debug output "+ inhalt + " already in AGlist")
            continue

    if firstRun is True:
        print("Frist run successfull, current ags: " + str(len(allAGs)))
        for AGurl in allAGs:
            print(AGurl)
    else:
        if newDetected is False:
            print(str(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")) + ": Nothing changed")
            writeCSV(inhalt)
        else:
            print("Something Changed, current ags: " + str(len(allAGs)))
            for AGurl in allAGs:
                print(AGurl)

    firstRun = False
    time.sleep(sleepTimer)

´´´´
```

Comment: I've read your question a couple of time and I'm still not sure what *exactly* you want to do. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Okay, well, I want to get an alert when a new user registers for the browser game. At the top of the picture you can see the relevant section that I want to monitor. If there is a change in this section, I would like to be notified.

Comment: How do you know that a player joins the game and how would you like to get notified?

Comment: If a player joins the list of names in this section will change. And behind these links in this sections is a unique ID. The ID is everytime +1, when a new player joins. 
The notification to me can go throgh a telegram bot but this will I do later